# can i use from jdk, Map 1key to multi value?

Tags: java, android, jsp

i want use map have multi value

ex)

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

but it seems too bad

may be jdk have map, this role?

thank so read this question

Comment: removed the swing tag, suspect that neither android nor jsp are related either ...

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid to define the mutimap the way you have done. JDK does not prvoide a collection called multimap. Althtough apache commons has defined a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) interface with implentation classes such as [MultiHashMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html) and [MultiValueMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html) .

If you don't want to use apache commons MultiMap then here is the tutorial to help you learn how you can create your own multimap using java HashMap:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [Map](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm)

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> sampleMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sampleList.add("Value1");
        sampleList.add("Value2");
        sampleList.add("Value3");

        sampleMap.put("Key1", sampleList);
        sampleMap.put("Key2", sampleList);
        sampleMap.put("Key3", sampleList);

        System.out.println("SampleMap : "+sampleMap);
```